# Google Chrome extension relative path

Tags: google-chrome

I'm developing a google chrome extension and I'm running into a relative path problem.
If I give a relative path to an image and open the plugin in a certain page it will look for that image in the website's path rather than the extension's.

Any ideas?

Comment: Post an example. This normally works.

Comment: here's an example:
background-image:url('sprites.png')

the error:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) sprites.png

If I use an absolute path such as, chrome-extensions://pfionnbgiepoddidhifofhiijoojachg/images, it finds the image without a problem.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you're using CSS in your extension pages (background, popup, infobar, etc) then you can use relative paths with a slash (`/`):

```
background-image:url("/sprites.png");
```

The above should work, everyone uses it. But, if your using it for content scripts and you can do the same for any css, you would need to use the [predefined message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n#overview-predefined) like:

```
background-image:url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/sprites.png');
```

If you want to programmatically set it, you can use the [chrome.extension.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL) syntax as following:

```
var url = chrome.extension.getURL('sprites.png');
```

These are the ways that you can refer to a specific url/image.

In addition, as [mentioned in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263230/why-do-chrome-extension-images-show-up-as-broken-when-added-to-the-dom), if you place your image assets in a directory, these files are not accessible in the web page DOM automatically. The developer should specify the resources that can be loaded the page by using the  "web_accessible_resources" setting in the manifest.json file:

Comment: let me see if I understand, I can only use relative paths in my backround, popup, infobar, and other pages like that. If I refer to an image in a content script or css I must use a predefined message as you explained above. Is that correct?

Comment: NB:  Currently this technique won't work for Content script CSS files, as they can't use predefined messages such as @@extension_id. For details, see bug 39899 (http://crbug.com/39899)

Comment: @@exension_id you can, the other custom predefined messages, you can't/

Comment: I see it:  it's ms-browser-extension://[[id]]/path

Comment: FYI: `chrome.extension.getURL()` [has been deprecated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension#method-getURL) as of Chrome v58 and replaced with `chrome.runtime.getURL()`.

Answer (score 11):

@mohamed's answer worked for me but it took my a while to put it all together. I've answered this else where but here is the solution that worked for me.

My solution.

With Menifest v2 you need to add `web_accessible_resources` to the file and then use `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/pattern.png` as the url in your css file.

**CSS:**

```
 #selector {
      background: #fff url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/images/pattern.png'); 
 }
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Extension Name",
  "description": "My Description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://mydomain.com/*"],
        "css": ["style.css"]
      }
    ],

  "permissions": [
    "https://mydomain.com/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {                    
            "19": "images/icon19.png",           
            "38": "images/icon38.png"          
       },
       "default_title": "My Extension Name"  
   },
   "web_accessible_resources": [
       "images/pattern.png"
     ]
}
```

p.s. Your manifest.json might look different to this one.

Comment: Is this answer valid (Does the chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/ trick work on firefox?)

Answer (score 2):

In some cases you might even use inline base64 encoding of the image. For example,

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAB..." />
```

Same you can apply to your CSS. You can find image encoders all over the web.