# "__MSG_@@extension_id__" doesn't work and webfonts don't load

Tags: css, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, webfonts

I'm developing a Google Chrome Extension which is injecting a stylesheet into a specific website I defined in `manifest.json`.

In the stylesheet are webfonts included with `@font-face` and `src: url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/[...]`, but `__MSG_@@extension_id__` doesn't seem to work and webfonts like Font Awesome just end up still showing squares.

manifest.json

```
"manifest_version": 2,

"content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [
            "http://[url].com/*"
        ],
        "css": ["assets/css/main.css"]
    }
],

"web_accessible_resources": ["assets/fonts/*", "assets/img/*"]
```

main.css

```
@font-face {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      src: url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.3.0");
      src: url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.3.0") format("embedded-opentype"), 
           url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.3.0") format("woff2"), 
           url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.3.0") format("woff"), 
           url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.3.0") format("truetype"), 
           url("chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.3.0#fontawesomeregular") format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }
```

I've already tried hardcoding my Extension ID in the url and it worked on my iMac and displayed Font Awesome correctly, but when I switched to my Macbook and hardcoded the new Extension ID in, it doesn't work anymore, but I'm sure I've did nothing wrong, since I just needed to change the ID. Now I wanted to try `__MSG_@@extension_id__` but it also doesn't work. Another try to embed the fonts with Base64 also failed. My other webfonts are Roboto and Open Sans included the same way.

It's like the Chrome Extension can't access to the fonts.

Comment: Relative URLs don't work, since these won't access the local extension but the website path. The fonts are stored in the extension itself. This is why the fonts and img folders need to be accessible with the `manifest.json`

Comment: if `main.css` is inside your extension then it uses local extension's paths. Look [here](https://github.com/thmzlt/github-tree/blob/master/font-awesome.css).

Comment: Yeah, but this will only work inside the extension itself like options.html but I'm using content scripts to inject the main.css into a website.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958617/google-chrome-extension-relative-path

Comment: I see. Maybe a more fully qualified path would work in manifest: `"assets/fonts/fontawesome/*"` ?

Comment: @timche paths in a css file are relative to the css location, not the webpage's. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718532/is-a-relative-path-in-a-css-file-relative-to-the-css-file

Comment: I already tried this, but it didn't work. The `*` wildcard allows all files and sub-folders, since on my iMac the hardcoded id can access the font.

Comment: @rsanchez please look at the third comment ...

Comment: I'd try `tabs.insertCSS`: 1. read css file using `getPackageDirectoryEntry`, 2. manually replace `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__` using `chrome.extension.getURL`.

Comment: Like I've written above, hardcoding works on my iMac but not on my Macbook and I don't know why. The extension ID will be generated relative to the path where the extension folder is located. This is a problem which I may to solve first.

Answer (score -1):

I saw the last comment on the question, **Same problem 4 years later :D**.
I am sure almost everyone already finds out the solution or they have got the things done in their way. But I think this will help others as the same question is being asked again and again.

**Answer**

```
const urlFontAwesomeWebFontEot = chrome.runtime.getURL('assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot')

const urlFontAwesomeWebFontSvg = chrome.runtime.getURL('assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg')

@font-face {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      src: url(${urlFontAwesomeWebFontEot});
      src: url(${urlFontAwesomeWebFontSvg}) format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }
```

I just created variables for two URLs but you can create as per your requirements.

> chrome.runtime.getURL **API help to get resource's absolute URL pointing extension**

**References**

- [Google Chrome extension relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3958617/google-chrome-extension-relative-path)
- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getURL

Answer (score -1):

I extend [Dinesh's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69039868/7913673) answer - there is the code that is ready to be pasted into js file:

```
const urlFontAwesomeWebFontEot = chrome.runtime.getURL('assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot')
const urlFontAwesomeWebFontSvg = chrome.runtime.getURL('assets/fonts/fontawesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg')

const newFontStyleSheet = document.createElement("style");

newFontStyleSheet.textContent = `
@font-face {
      font-family: 'FontAwesome';
      src: url(${urlFontAwesomeWebFontEot});
      src: url(${urlFontAwesomeWebFontSvg}) format("svg");
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal; }
`;

document.head.appendChild(newFontStyleSheet);
```

Answer (score -1):

### Just follow below steps:

Lets assume we have a font in `fonts` folder:

```
\fonts
    font.woff
manifest.json
```

- update your `manifest.json` with

```
...

"web_accessible_resources": [
    "fonts/*"
],

...
```

- in CSS file provide url `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/font.woff`

---

If you don't provide `web_accessible_resources` permissions, request for font will be blocked (since manifest version 2 including ver 2).

---

**References:**

- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv2/manifest/web_accessible_resources/
- https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/i18n/