# Loading embedded fonts from a Chrome Extension content script

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

This is how I'm loading embedded fonts in my Chrome Extension:

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    // more stuff
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "css": ["style.css"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],
    // more stuff
    "web_accessible_resources": [
        {
            "resources": ["*.ttf"],
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
        }
    ]
}
```

**style.css:**

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Nunito';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/Nunito-Medium.ttf');
}
```

The font loads in my Chrome Extension if the font is being called from `style.css`. However, if it's being called from `content.js` (inserted with [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)), I get this error:

> GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED

I think, for some reason, `__MSG_@@extension_id__` isn't working when called from `content.js`.

```
___CSS_LOADER_EXPORT___.push([module.id, "extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/Nunito-Medium.ttf') // more stuff
```

What could be the reason, and how to make `__MSG_@@extension_id__` work in `content.js`? Or how to load embedded fonts from `content.js` or any JavaScript file in a Chrome Extension?

Comment: The definition of the ttf file storage folder is inconsistent between manifest.json and style.css.

Comment: Have you tried these? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401981/msg-extension-id-doesnt-work-and-webfonts-dont-load

Comment: @wOxxOm What documentation? This is what I found: "The special message @@extension_id can be used in the CSS and **JavaScript files.**" https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/i18n/

Comment: @wOxxOm Oh, I see. Thanks for spotting that. Maybe convert all this information to an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation [says](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/i18n/#:%7E:text=manifest.json%20and%20CSS) that these magical `MSG` constants are for "manifest.json and CSS files" and then [mistakenly says](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/i18n/#:%7E:text=The%20special%20message%20%40%40extension_id) that `@@extension_id` can be used in JavaScript files, but it's not true.

In JS code we can use [chrome.runtime.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getURL):

```js
var url = chrome.runtime.getURL('fonts/Nunito-Medium.ttf');
```

It's also compatible with `"use_dynamic_url": true` in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/manifest/web_accessible_resources/) which uses a special random id instead of the extension id.